# change the dataframe on the basis of column Region

Tags: r

Actually i want to change the data frame on the basis of column Region.

i want to check the column Regions if there is any text in column house for "!UK" in region and for that add a new row and paste the text in new row in column house.

then i m checking column house and separating the text on the basis ";" in new row.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <-  tibble(Region = c("AU","USA","CA","USA","!UK","AU","USA","CA","!UK"),
              lock = c(1,1,NA,1,NA,1,NA,1,NA),
              type= c("sale",NA,NA,"target","target",NA,"sale",NA,"target"),
              House =c("Tagore house","Gandhi house",NA,"Flexible;Tagore house;Gandhi house","Tagore house",NA,"Flexible;Gandhi house","Gandhi house","Gandhi house"))

step_1 <- df %>% mutate(g_l=replace_na(str_detect(House,
                                                   ";"),0),
                         g_num = if_else(g_l,cumsum(g_l),0)) |>
    separate_longer_delim(cols="House",delim=";") |> group_by(g_num)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `uncount` to add new rows where the 'Region' is '!UK' and replace the values in other columns to NA based on the Region value

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
  separate_longer_delim(cols = House, delim = ";") %>% 
  uncount(1 + (Region == "!UK")) %>%
  group_by(grp = rleid(Region)) %>% 
  mutate(Region = replace(Region, !duplicated(Region) & Region == "!UK", 
     NA), across(c(lock, type),  ~replace(.x, is.na(Region), NA))) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-grp) %>% 
  mutate(House = replace(House, Region == "!UK", NA))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 14 × 4
   Region  lock type   House       
   <chr>  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>       
 1 AU         1 sale   Tagore house
 2 USA        1 <NA>   Gandhi house
 3 CA        NA <NA>   <NA>        
 4 USA        1 target Flexible    
 5 USA        1 target Tagore house
 6 USA        1 target Gandhi house
 7 <NA>      NA <NA>   Tagore house
 8 !UK       NA target <NA>        
 9 AU         1 <NA>   <NA>        
10 USA       NA sale   Flexible    
11 USA       NA sale   Gandhi house
12 CA         1 <NA>   Gandhi house
13 <NA>      NA <NA>   Gandhi house
14 !UK       NA target <NA>
```

Comment: i mean if want to skip this condition separate_longer_delim(cols = House, delim = ";") %>%  and want to update dataframe for column region have UK and update text in new row for column house. also please try to explain line by line

Comment: can you provide a separate solution for this ..??